# How can i clearInterval from a popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, intervals, window.opener

SOLUTION: (Can't post a solution on my own question for some reason...)

I found a solution to my problem by creating a function in my index file which I then called from my popup window.

index:

```
function clearRefreshStatusInterval() {
  clearInterval(refreshStatusInterval);
  refreshStatusInterval = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("REFRESH");
  },1000);
}
```

popup:

```
$(window).mousemove(function() {
  window.opener.clearRefreshStatusInterval();
});
```

---

QUESTION:

I am trying to clear a setInterval-timer from mousemovement in a popup window. It works well in the index file.

This code is in my index file (does work):

```
var refreshStatusInterval = setInterval(function(){
  refreshStatus();
},10000);

$(window).mousemove(function() {
  clearInterval(refreshStatusInterval);
  refreshStatusInterval = setInterval(function(){
    refreshStatus();
  },10000);
});
```

This code is in my popup window (does not work):

```
$(window).mousemove(function() {
  window.opener.clearInterval(window.opener.refreshStatusInterval);

  window.opener.refreshStatusInterval = window.opener.setInterval(function(){
    window.opener.refreshStatus();
  },10000);
});
```

The timer wont reset for me, anyone know how to do this?

Comment: fiddle please . http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b8hEp/14/

This is the best jsfiddle i could do. I didnt quite understand how to work with popup windows in jsfiddle.